# Easy question - Is this a Cycle?

Tags: directed-graph

I have a directed graph. Is the following a cycle? Do the arrows have a specific direction in a cycle?

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" answers that satisfy you to build up StackOverflow street cred :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a *directed* cycle. However, if you permit consideration of the underlying *undirected* graph (by forgetting the orientations of the edges), then there is an *undirected* cycle. It all depends on which category you're interested in!

Comment: +1 This is a DAG with multiple topological sort orders. To cause a cycle though you need only remove the direction of *one* of the parallel edges.

Comment: +1 I knew there was a better way to explain this than my long, rambling answer.

Comment: Oh, is that a [computer science term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)? For me topologies have open sets and homotopy groups, but I'm always open to learning something new :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't a cycle. Remember that a cycle is a closed path. Then the final vertex match with the initial vertex. Here you don't have a closed path...